# Disabling finish button depending value of textbox

Tags: java, eclipse-neon

In java I have a wizard created with only one wizard page.I have a label with a corresponding text box. I have given a default text to the text box "name". Now I want to disable the button if the text is "name" or is empty.Using Key Listener didn't work.So what listener do I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a code sample?

Depending on that you may be able to override the "public boolean canFinish()" method to toggle the state of the button.